# Machine cannot resolve his own name - System.Net.WebException: "The remote name could not be resolved"

Tags: .net, wcf, dns

We have several web-services running under IIS, calling each other using WCF.

In the URL's the machine name is used. (Lets say: serverXYZ)

Since a while now, we get the following error:

```
Type : System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : There was no endpoint listening at http://serverXYZ:81/bla/bla.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Type : System.Net.WebException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
    Message : The remote name could not be resolved: 'serverXYZ'
```

Calls to services on other machines work.
Calls from other services to this machine work.
IIS at serverXYZ is running.
PING at serverXYZ to serverXYZ results in `::1` and is working.

Anyone?

Comment: Have you tried the firewall or other permission-related Settings, and see if the bindings match.

Comment: @Jiayao: Thanks for your reaction. About the firewall: What settings are you referring to? Inbound and outbound connections work. Connections to "locahost" fail. 
About bindings: I suspect this is beyond WCF, because the error is thrown by WebException (not able to find 'serverXYZ'). If it was a binding concern I would expect a WCF-related exception.

Comment: You're right. The error thrown is a WebException that is not specific, and maybe you can try to get a more detailed log to determine whether it is a local network problem or something else.